# Select random faces but no adjacent faces

Tags: modeling, selection-tools

If I execute "Select random faces", even if I set the selection ratio lower than I want, I can still see adjacent selected faces. Is there a way to make selected faces not adjacent (no shared vertices), other than manually deselecting such faces?

[image]

Comment: try looking for some python for this on API

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Another bmesh script**

[image]

Similarly to @gorgeous

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from random import choice 

context = bpy.context
ob = context.object
me = ob.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)

ratio = 0.5
for f in bm.faces:
    f.select_set(False)
    
faces = set(bm.faces)
chosen = 0

while faces and (chosen / len(bm.faces)) < ratio:
    face = choice(list(faces))
    face.select_set(True)
    faces -= set(f for v in face.verts for f in v.link_faces)
    chosen += 1
    
bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me)
```

Answer (score 5):

This script should do it. You should only have 1 object selected and be in edit mode. Some code borrowed from [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/114758/86891).

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from random import randint

faces_to_select = 15  # Change this for the number of faces to select.

bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='DESELECT')

mesh = bpy.context.object.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(mesh)

faces_pool = bm.faces[:]
for face_idx in range(faces_to_select):
    if not faces_pool:
        break
    if len(faces_pool) == 1:
        select_face = faces_pool.pop(0)
    else:
        select_face = faces_pool.pop(randint(0, len(faces_pool) - 1))
    select_face.select_set(True)
    for face in set(f for v in select_face.verts for f in v.link_faces if f in faces_pool):
        faces_pool.remove(face)

bmesh.update_edit_mesh(mesh)
```

[How to run a script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11604548/7092409)

Result :
[image]